# How to expose a bundle configuration with unknown number of nodes

Tags: symfony, config

I would like to expose a bundle configuration like this:

```
bundle_name:
     items:
         itemNameA: itemNameA_property
         itemNameB: itemNameB_property
```

The problem is that I don't know the number of items or its names, it depend of each user configuration. The Symfony documentation is very clear when you know the node name, but what about if not. So, how I can load the `$rootNode` without knowing the names or the amount of items?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
$rootNode = $treeBuilder->root('bundle_name');
$rootNode
    ->children()                                
    ->arrayNode('items')
        ->useAttributeAsKey('name')
        ->prototype('variable')->end()
     ->end()
->end();
```